# manifest packageName error in android studio

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, manifest

i am getting problem in manifest file it giving error that is mentioned below..

> "Error:Cannot read packageName from I:\Android\MyApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml"

My Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="nkdroid.truelovequotes" platformBuildVeormBuildVersionName="7.0">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>rsionCode="24" platf
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.app.MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <service android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.firebase.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.CategoryListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.MoreAppsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme"/>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"/>
    <provider android:authorities="nkdroid.truelovequotes.firebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashReceiverService" android:process=":background_crash"/>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashSenderService" android:process=":background_crash"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap it to `manifest` tag, just put you package name here instead of  package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME":

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>rsionCode="24" platf
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.app.MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <service android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.firebase.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.CategoryListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes.activities.MoreAppsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme"/>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"/>
    <provider android:authorities="nkdroid.truelovequotes.firebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="nkdroid.truelovequotes"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashReceiverService" android:process=":background_crash"/>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashSenderService" android:process=":background_crash"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: well maybe, but there was not just 5 minutes ago... 
Try "com.nkdroid.truelovequotes".
Have you changed this string?

Comment: It was actually. If you look at the original source of the question

Comment: You have reference `I:\Android\MyApp\app\src\main\``and package name with `nkdroid.truelovequotes`. If you copy this project from somewhere you should just fallback to the source of your problem - how to rename project in Android Studio....

Comment: @cricket_007, man, history is public, I can see edit 9 mins ago, question was asked 19 mins, do you really want me to discuss it?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to tell me. This isn't my question. Point is, the package name was there already

Comment: @cricket_007, 
edited 15 mins ago by you
answered 19 mins ago by me.
Don't edit question and then claim other people's answers because point is that it was not package name defined in first version of this question (right when I answered it).